# How to query for many to many relationship between products and filters in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables viz. tb_filters, tb_products, and tb_products_to_filters. The structure of these tables along with some dummy data is given by:

**tb_filters:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_filters`
(
    `filter_id` INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `filter_name` VARCHAR (255)
);

INSERT INTO `tb_filters`
(`filter_name`)
VALUES ('USB'),
('High Speed'),
('Wireless'),
('Ethernet');
```

[image]

**tb_products:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_products`
(
    `product_id` INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `product_name` VARCHAR (255)
);

INSERT INTO `tb_products`
(`product_name`)
VALUES ('Ohm precision shunt resistor'),
('Orchestrator Libraries'),
('5cm scanner connection'),
('Channel isolated digital'),
('Network Interface Module');
```

[image]

**tb_products_to_filters:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_products_to_filters`
(
    `id` INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `product_id` INT (11),
    `filter_id` INT (11)
);

INSERT INTO `tb_products_to_filters`
(`product_id`, `filter_id`)
VALUES (1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 3),
(1, 3);
```

[image]

By looking into above "tb_products_to_filters" table, my required queries are:

When filter id = 1 and 3 are selected via checkbox on the page, all those products which belong to filter id 1 as well as filter id 3 must be fetched from the database. In this case, the product with id 1 should come.

Second, when only one filter (say id = 3) is checked, then all those products which fall under this id should be fetched. In this condition, the products id 1, 3 and 4 will come.

If filter id 2 is selected, then only one product with id = 2 will come.

If combination of filter (2 and 3) is selected, then no product will come because there is no product which belongs to both of them.

What is the way of writing queries to obtain above goal?

Please note that I want to include columns: product_id, product_name, filter_id and filter_name to display data in table result set.

**EDIT:**

The output should match below when filter ids 1 and 3 were checked:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I'm trying below query to fetch results when filter 1 and 3 were checked:

```
SELECT `p`.`product_id`, `p`.`product_name`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `f`.`filter_id` ORDER BY `f`.`filter_id` SEPARATOR ', ') AS filter_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `f`.`filter_name` ORDER BY `f`.`filter_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS filter_name 
FROM `tb_products` AS `p` INNER JOIN `tb_products_to_filters` AS `ptf` 
ON `p`.`product_id` = `ptf`.`product_id` INNER JOIN `tb_filters` AS `f` 
ON `ptf`.`filter_id` = `f`.`filter_id` GROUP BY `p`.`product_id` 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `ptf`.`filter_id` SEPARATOR ', ') = ('1,3') 
ORDER BY `p`.`product_id`
```

But unfortunately, it returns an empty set. Why?

Comment: Note that the surrogate key in `tb_products_to_filters` is redundant, as you have a perfectly good natural key on `(product_id,filter_id)`. Also (and I admit this is a personal gripe), given that every object in SQL is a table (unless it's a view) the tb_ prefix seems unnecessary.

Comment: The key `id` in `tb_products_to_filters` is not redundant. It's an auto-incremented primary key. Both other columns `product_id` and `filter_id` don't have unique values. Therefore `id` column was necessary to manipulate and query this table further. Also `tb_` prefix is not unnecessary. It's a personal preference. It's an ethical nomenclature. Don't you know WordPress does the same by prefixing its tables with `wp_`?

Comment: They have unique values when considered in combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause with `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT t.product_id,tp.product_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.filter_id) as filter_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tb.filter_name) as filter_name
FROM tb_products_to_filters t
INNER JOIN tb_filters tb ON(t.filter_id = tb.filter_id)
INNER JOIN tb_products tp ON(t.product_id = tp.product_id)
WHERE t.filter_id IN(1,3)
GROUP BY t.product_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.filter_id) = 2
```

You can adjust this any way you want. Note that the number of arguments placed inside the `IN()` should be the same as the `COUNT(..) = X`

**EDIT:**

A DISTINCT keyword is required in GROUP_CONCAT while fetching those columns otherwise all the filters would come in the list. I tried it by doing

```
SELECT t.product_id,tp.product_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.filter_id ORDER BY `t`.`filter_id` SEPARATOR ', ') as filter_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb.filter_name ORDER BY tb.filter_name SEPARATOR ', ') as filter_name
FROM tb_products_to_filters t
INNER JOIN tb_filters tb ON(t.filter_id = tb.filter_id)
INNER JOIN tb_products tp ON(t.product_id = tp.product_id)
WHERE t.filter_id IN(1,3)
GROUP BY t.product_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct t.filter_id) = 2
```

But still all the filter names (Ethernet, High Speed, USB, Wireless) are coming in the list. How to list only those filter names whose corresponding  filter id (1, 3) are in the string?

[image]

Comment: Your query is wrong! `#1054 - Unknown column 't.product_filter' in 'having clause'`

Comment: I updated my question. I want all columns. So you are wrong by saying I don't need first 2 tables.

Comment: @user5307298 Try to make some efforts on your own you know, and next time,explain your self better. The query is updated now.

Comment: I explained very well in my question as much as I could. I had already been trying but didn't post them in my question because they could lead to some confusion in other users. That's why I just wrote about my requirements of queries.

Comment: You explain the requierments, you didn't provide the output which can lead to a various of different solutions! A question needs to include data sample, input and expected output. That doesn't matter now, did my query solved your problem?

Comment: Sorry @sagi, you are right. Though I posted my question along with data sample but didn't display expected output. Yes solutions can vary. But now I updated my question and put an image to show you all what do I really need to get. Your query worked but didn't help me to get what I really wanted. Hopefully my editing will help you to understand my requirement a better.

Comment: Yes it worked but not 100% perfect. I edited your solution but I think it won't be visible to you yet. The `DISTINCT` keyword is required in fetching column names otherwise all filters will come in the list. I did but still all filters names are coming in the list. Though `DISTINCT` worked for filter ids but not for filter names.

Comment: Also I am wondering why did you use the order of joining these 3 tables as: `products_to_filters` to `filters` to `products`. I was joining `products` to `products_to_filters` to `filters`. Does the difference in ordering these tables really matter?

Comment: I approved the edit. The order of the join doesn't matter when dealing with `INNER JOIN` , only on `LEFT\RIGHT JOIN` , so it's basically the same as your order. @user5307298

Comment: Yes right; doesn't matter in INNER JOIN. But where did you edit? In yours or in my edit? Since either didn't make any difference. Same result. All filter names are coming in the list `Ethernet, High Speed, USB, Wireless`. How to fix it? Only 1 and 3 filter names should be there?

Comment: I updated my question with second edit. I posted my own query to fetch the result. But it also doesn't work. Can you please look into it?

Comment: Huh that's another typo , the condition `t.filter_id = t.filter_id` is wrong and should be `t.filter_id = tb.filter_id` . Now :)

Comment: The query worked like a charm. Oh yes that was typo! I adjusted the query to suit my order of tables. Thanks friend.